# Having problems with Post via python

Tags: python, http, post, cgi

I'm having a bit of trouble. I'm trying to send a POST and trying to follow the documentation, but I can't seem to get it right.

on github: https://github.com/trtmn/Python

**Pull requests welcomed!**

```
# Getting documentation from :
#https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html 
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'
values = {"username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #general and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

looks like I needed to stringify it as JSON (which I knew, but didn't know how). Thanks to Tim G. for the assist.

So here's the functional code:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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'
values = {"username": "webhookbot", "text": "This is posted to #general and comes from a bot named webhookbot.", "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"}

data = json.dumps(values)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using httplib as an alternative for POST:

*import httplib

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
conn.request('POST',urI,request_body, headers)    
response = conn.getresponse()
resp_status=response.status
resp_reason=response.reason
resp_body=response.read()
conn.close()*
```

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the problem but if I add a slash to the end of your url I do receive a response when I execute your code.

url = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/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/'